# How do I add a space to .serialize form return?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm playing a bit with forms in html and jQuery and I've got a problem adding a space before and after my `=` sign. I'm still a beginner, and at times I dont know 100% what I'm doing, so if you've got any tips, feel free to chip in with them as well. So far this is what I've got:

```
        <form id='target'>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Name' name='name' id='name' ><br />
            <input type='text' placeholder='Address1' name='address1' class='input' /><br />
            <input type='text' placeholder='Address2' name='address2' class='input' /><br />
            <input type='text' placeholder='Postcode' name='postcode' class='input' /><br />
            <input type='text' placeholder='Country' name='country' class='input' /><br />
            <input class='input' type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />
        </form>
```

and my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#target').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = $("input[name='name']").serialize();
    var address1 = $("input[name='address1']").serialize();
    var address2 = $("input[name='address2']").serialize();
    var postcode = $("input[name='postcode']").serialize();
    var country = $("input[name='country']").serialize();
    $('#cont8').html("<div class='formreturn'>"+ name + "<br />"+ address1 + "<br />" + address2 + "<br />"+ postcode + "<br />"+ country +"</div>");
    }); 
});
```

This `return`s:

```
Name=MyName <br />
Address1=MyStreet1 <br />
Address2=MyStreet2 <br />
Postcode=MyPostcode <br />
Country=MyCountry
```

Which is fine (although the code might be a bit messy?!)
But I want to add a space on either side of the `=` sign. How do I do that?
Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `name.replace('=',' = ');` on each string.